# Specify type for dynamic variable in named constructor

Tags: dart, types

Consider the following class.

```
class Test {
  final String foo;
  final dynamic bar;

  Test({this.foo, this.bar});

  Test.barInt({this.foo, this.bar});
}
```

How would the field `bar` be speified as an `int` in the named constructur `barInt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just specify the type before the parameter:

```dart
Test.barInt({this.foo, int this.bar});
```

be aware that later in the code it is possible to change the value of `bar` to any type from its setter.
You might want to check out [generics](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics) for this use case.